# index all files inside a folder in solr

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, directory

I am having troubles indexing a folder in solr

example-data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>  
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="files" 
        dataSource="null" 
        rootEntity="false"
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        baseDir="C:\Temp\" fileName=".*"
        recursive="true"
        onError="skip">
            <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
            <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />

            <entity
                name="documentImport"
                processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                format="text">
                <field column="file" name="fileName"/>
                <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                <field column="text" name="text"/>

            </entity>
    </entity>
    </document>
```

then I create the schema.xml:

```
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="fileName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="size" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="lastModified" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

finally I modify the file solrConfig.xml adding the requesthandler and the dataImportHandler and dataImportHandler-extra jars:

```
    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">example-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I run it and the result is:

[image: result]

Inside that folder there are like 20.000 files in diferent formats (.py,.java,.wsdl, etc)

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: seems like the recursive="true" is not working in some way, I tried with a subfolder and the information of the subfolder is indexed properly. But the root cause I really don't know at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Solr logs . Answer for what is the `Root Cause` will definitely be there . I also faced same situation once and found through solr logs that my `DataImportHandler` was throwing exceptions because of `encrypted documents` present in the folder . Your reasons may be different, but first analyze your solr logs, execute your `entity` again in `DataImport` section, and then check the immediate logs for errors by going on the `logging` section on admin page . If you are getting errors other than I what I mentioned , post them here , so they can be understood and deciphered .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :). I looked in the logs and seems like there is an issue when Solr is trying to index the .png images, so what I am doing right now is making a list of all files that don't have useful information for me like (png,jpg,swf,etc) and don't index them.

Comment: Post here what are you getting in your logs . And , would like you to accept my answer if it helped you :)